# ui-router change params id (mongoddb)

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, angular-ui-router

I'm using **angularJS**,**nodejs** and **mongodb**. When I create state, I have define state :

```
 .state('detail', {
        url: '/detail/:id',
        templateUrl: 'views/detail-products.html',
        controller: 'DetailCtrl'
    })
```

when url :

```
localhost:9001/detail/53dbad2a22af464a799a9896
```

I want rename id :

```
localhost:9001/detail/chi-tiet-1
```

can someone help me?